# Why am I getting this error code in the console output?

Tags: python

I am getting this console output error when I run my code. I'm not sure what else to try but it says that there is something wrong with the line `from scanner import Scanner`.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Scanner' from 'scanner' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scanner.cpython-37m-darwin.so)`

```
import sys
from scanner import Scanner
from functools import cmp_to_key
```

Comment: What happens if you just `import scanner` instead of `from scanner import Scanner`?

Comment: I would get an error saying ```'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable```

Comment: But for a different line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you install this `scanner` package from? I suspect you are using [this package](https://pypi.org/project/scanner/), which seems to provide `StringScanner` and `StringRegexp`, but not `Scanner`.